# Apache Camel is not capturing the SOAP service response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I'm using Apache Camel 2.19.2 DSL and trying to consume a soap service hosted in a different server. My camel code is -

```
SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("<Service Class Package Path>");
soap.setContextPath("Root element package path");
soap.setVersion("1.1");
from("direct:invokeSOAPService")
    .process(new Processor1()) //Constructs the main message body that will be set as body of the soap-Envelope
    .removeHeaders("*")
    .setHeader(Exchange.SOAP_ACTION, simple("Soap Action of the service from ASDL"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("text/xml"))
    .marshal(soap)
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "Request xml===========>${body}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "Posting request to server url")
    .to("cxf://http://<ip>:<port>/<wsdl server location without ?wsdl>?serviceClass=<qualified service class name without .class extension>&dataFormat=MESSAGE&synchronous=true&continuationTimeout=100000&serviceName={<target-name-space-name>}<service-name>&endpointName={<target-name-space-name>}<service port name>")
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "Posted request successfully to server url")
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOG, "Received response from server ==========>${body}")
.end();
```

Application is able to generate the soap-request and able to post the same to the server and server is sending back the soap response (as confirmed by the owner of the soap server) but I can't see the response at my application end.

it is printing the request xml using below log:

```
Request xml===========> <soap request xml>
Posting request to server url
**org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.AbstractDataFormatFeature.removeInterceptors><removing the interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter@58811c5b
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.AbstractDataFormatFeature.removeInterceptors><removing the interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassInInterceptor@1d25437
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.AbstractDataFormatFeature.removeInterceptors><removing the interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderInInterceptor@4451805d
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.AbstractDataFormatFeature.removeInterceptors><removing the interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@2514dd3d
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.AbstractDataFormatFeature.removeInterceptors><removing the interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@75a76e00**
Posted request successfully to server url
Received response from server ==========> **PRINTING THE REQUEST XML**
```

Could you please help me to understand the issue, why camel is not able to capture the response! It is because of those camel internal remove methods?

Could you please help me to capture the response.

Comment: There are many possible reasons. I mean, what do you get as http status code? Do you get a SOAP fault? What does it say on the server when you send your request? Does the server actually receive your request correctly?

Comment: In & Out Exchange headers and body are blank. Not able to see any response code.

Comment: I think you need to troubleshoot a bit more to see why they are blank. That usually indicates a break somewhere.